# How to avoid PL/pgSQL loops? What are performance alternatives?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, plpgsql, database-optimization

I have close to 200M records in my tables. My migration script runs very slowly (for hours).

**---My OLD Tables---**

orders_old table **30M row count**

| id | createdDate | status | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000376453 | 2021-10-14 | completed | 286 |
| 1000368038 | 2021-11-24 | cancelled | 334 |

order_status_history_old table **150M row count**

| modified_date | order_id | old_status | new_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-22 | 1000376453 | created | accepted |
| 2022-06-23 | 1000376453 | accepted | completed |
| 2022-07-16 | 1000368038 | created | accepted |
| 2022-07-16 | 1000368038 | accepted | completed |
| 2022-07-20 | 1000368038 | completed | cancelled |

**---My NEW Tables---**

history_info table

| id | date | updated_by |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

order_history table

| id | rev | rev_type | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

**---My PlSql Code---**

```
DO $$
DECLARE
ORDER_TABLE_RECORD                      RECORD;
HISTORY_INFO_ID                         INTEGER;
ORDER_STATUS_HISTORY_TABLE_RECORD       RECORD;
BEGIN

FOR ORDER_TABLE_RECORD IN SELECT * FROM ORDERS_OLD LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'ORDER STARTED %', ORDER_TABLE_RECORD.ID;

FOR ORDER_STATUS_HISTORY_TABLE_RECORD IN SELECT * FROM ORDER_STATUS_HISTORY_OLD OH WHERE OH.ORDER_ID = ORDER_TABLE_RECORD.ID LOOP

HISTORY_INFO_ID := NEXTVAL('HISTORY_INFO_SEQ');
INSERT INTO HISTORY_INFO(ID, DATE, UPDATED_BY)
VALUES(HISTORY_INFO_ID, ORDER_STATUS_HISTORY_TABLE_RECORD.last_modified_date, ORDER_STATUS_HISTORY_TABLE_RECORD.status_changer);

INSERT INTO ORDER_HISTORY(ID, REV, REVTYPE, STATUS)
VALUES(ORDER_TABLE_RECORD.ID :: BIGINT, HISTORY_INFO_ID, 1, 'NEW');

END LOOP;


END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Also, I'm trying alternative scripts like below script but I am getting an error.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
BEGIN

WITH OSHO_DATA AS (
    select osho.order_id, osho.new_order_status, OSHO.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, OSHO.STATUS_CHANGER
    from orders_old oo
    left join order_status_history_old osho on osho.order_id = oo.id
),
HI_DATA AS (
INSERT INTO HISTORY_INFO(ID, DATE, UPDATED_BY)
SELECT NEXTVAL('HISTORY_INFO_SEQ'), OSHO_DATA.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, OSHO_DATA.STATUS_CHANGER
FROM OSHO_DATA LIMIT 1
RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO ORDER_HISTORY(ID, REV, REVTYPE, STATUS)
SELECT OSHO_DATA.order_id :: BIGINT, HI_DATA.ID, 1, GET_STATUS_CODE(OSHO_DATA.new_order_status)
FROM OSHO_DATA, HI_DATA;

END $$;
```

How do I migrate my old data to my new tables quickly with performance?

NOTE: The reason why I use loop instead of bulk insert is because I use the id after the first insert in the next insert process.

Comment: A construction like this should work: INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ... RETURNING ... And you can do this within a CTE for multiple INSERT statements.

Comment: Hi @FrankHeikens thanks for your advice but I am getting an error for this.

Error: INSERT has more target columns than expressions

Comment: Update your question with the SQL involved, we have no idea what you're doing

Comment: You are right. I updated the question and I added the query.

Comment: INSERTED_HISTORY_INFO_DATA doesn't return anything, that can not work. And what does GET_STATUS_CODE() do? And please post the entire error message including all hints and details about the error.

Comment: I updated the query. GET_STATUS_CODE is a function. It returns a constant value. It is not important something.

[2022-11-15 00:11:45] [42601] ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions
[2022-11-15 00:11:45] Hint: The insertion source is a row expression containing the same number of columns expected by the INSERT. Did you accidentally use extra parentheses?
[2022-11-15 00:11:45] Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 31 at SQL statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249602/discussion-between-oguzhan-cevik-and-frank-heikens).

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: "SELECT(", drop the ( and later the ) as well.

Comment: This is a mess, the field names in your functions do not match those in your table data examples e.g. `ORDER_STATUS_HISTORY_TABLE_RECORD.status_changer`,  `osho.order_id`, `osho.new_order_status`, etc.